# Controlling access to a communication layer

Tags: java, c#, security, architecture

I have a number of applications (.Net & Java) which communicate with each other using a communication layer. 
I now need to extend the communication layer to allow 3rd party applications access it - as shown below.
However while I want to ensure that my applications can still access all available methods in the communication layer I want to limit access to the 3rd party applications.

In essence therefore I need to find a way for my applications to prove that they really are mine. Naturally I can use public/private key encryption or a unique hash in each message however this is slowing down communication between my apps to a pretty unacceptable limit. Does anyone have any other ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Use different endpoints for public and private access

Comment: @RAJ - I already have different endpoints setup but what is to stop a malicious 3rd party app from coming in on the wrong endpoint ?

Comment: Sorry one thing you can have is service router, external thirdparty will have only access to routed service. This router service will take care of necessary security.

Comment: The vast bulk of the overhead should be in establishing the link. After that encryption should be minimal.

Comment: Why don't you name it "communication api" and use "appKey/appSecret" scheme, usual for such many public APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost perfectly describe the concept of [Enterprise application integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration). The two patterns that you can use together for the

> I want to ensure that my applications can still access all available methods in the communication layer I want to limit access to the 3rd party applications.

Here the first one - **[Mediation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation)** can help you as a broker between your own applications. Whenever an interesting event occurs in one application an integration module in the EAI system is notified. The module then propagates the changes to other relevant applications.

In the part of

> need to extend the communication layer to allow 3rd party applications access it

The **[Federation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_(information_technology))** will ensure that all calls from the 'outside world' to any of the applications are front-ended by the EAI system. As it acts  as the overarching *Facade* across multiple applications. The EAI system is configured to expose only the relevant information and interfaces of the underlying applications to the outside world, and performs all interactions with the underlying applications on behalf of the requester.

For the

> communication layer

you can look at the *Communication architectures* section, that is also mention there. In my current Project we use [Tibco](http://www.tibco.com/).

Answer (score -2):

Create a web service for communication to occur and use that service for all your apps to communicate to each other.
Also continue to use public/private key encryption or a unique hash in each message which service take.